# How to plot a value of an object in a dataframe with matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I have a following movies dataset:

[image: Dataset]

I need to make a categorial plot with `matplotlib.pyplot.bar` for `production_companies` column.

Yet this column contains a list with a single object (**Ex**: `[{"name": "Ingenious Film Partners", "id": 289...`).

I only need to plot the name of the company. How can I extract it and do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
convert = lambda x : [i['name'] for i in x]
data = movie_set['production_companies'].apply(json.loads).apply(convert)
```